# URL cache-busting parameters with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, browser-cache

I'm using RequireJS (the jQuery version) and I want to append GET parameters to my scripts to prevent unwanted caching.

I'm using [the urlArgs parameter](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), as suggested in the docs. This is my `app-build.js` file:

```
({
  appDir: "../",
  baseUrl: "scripts/",
  urlArgs: "cache=v2",
  ...
```

Then I build the project as follows:

```
$ node ../../r.js -o app.build.js
```

The output in app-build directory now contains both `require-jquery.js`, which is the same file as previously, and `require-jquery.js?cache=v2`, which is blank.

The `index.html` file doesn't seem to have any references to `cache=v2`. And when I load the page in a browser, I don't see any `cache=v2` parameters appended to any of the scripts.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The docs on urlArgs:

“During development it can be useful to use this,
however be sure to remove it before deploying your code”

and [this issue from Github](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/247), James Burke:
“do not try to use urlArgs during build”

Answer (score 1):

The urlArgs parameter is more of a runtime configuration (i.e., only understood by RequireJS, not the r.js optimizer), seemingly due to its author's [stated](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/376#issuecomment-7058617) belief that it is only suited to development (and "bad" dev servers that don't send proper headers). So you'd either need to configure it in your require.config call (in a .js file loaded by require.js, typically main.js or config.js):

```
require.config({
    // other config, like paths and shim

    urlArgs: "cache=v2"
});
```

Or, per this other SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724555/466874), you'd define it in directly in a `<script>` block before loading require.js.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a different build.js file for the optimizer vs the build.js file you use running the live app. Based on your description, the optimizer script doesn't seem to properly handle the urlArgs parameter (since it's outputting a file called require-jquery.js?cache=v2).

I wouldn't expect cache=v2 to show up in index.html (why would it?), but you're right to expect it in the network activity log.